# ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Network is unreachable

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitbucket

Unable to git pull, clone, push from AWS ec2 to bitbucket.

Getting error "ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

EC2 details - Ubuntu 16.04
Git version - 2.4.7

Comment: Bitbucket has partial outage. Check https://status.bitbucket.org/

Answer (score -2):

I am also not able to connect AWS servers ( in mumbai zone).

stderr: ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

There could be issue with Bitbucket. Seems like presently Bitbucket is down.

[image: Bitbucket status page]